# HTML entities converted into their character values when JSON read from data attribute

Tags: javascript, json, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to access a stringified JSON array in a data attribute. When I grab the value with `$(...).data('whatever')` or `$(...).attr('data-whatever')`, however, HTML entities (e.g. `&quot;`) in the content of the JSON get converted to their character representation (e.g. `"`) which causes the JSON string to be misinterpreted when parsed.

For example, if the value of my data attribute is `["Oberlin City Club: Opera Preview","Documentary Screening &quot;Still Dreaming: Frances Walker at 93&quot;"]`, reading this with `$(...).data()` returns `["Oberlin City Club: Opera Preview","Documentary Screening "Still Dreaming: Frances Walker at 93""]`. Why did JavaScript convert `&quot;` into `"`? How can I read the data attribute without converting `&quot;` into `"`?

```js
console.log($('div').attr('data-titles'));
console.log(JSON.parse($('div').attr('data-titles')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-titles='["Oberlin City Club: Opera Preview","Documentary Screening &quot;Still Dreaming: Frances Walker at 93&quot;"]'></div>
```

Comment: Javscript didn't do this, the browser converts entities when it parses the HTML. Look at the DIV in the DOM inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did JavaScript convert `&quot;` into "?

In this case, it didn't. By using `&quot;` in your response, the browser parses that as `"` and that is what gets put into the attribute. This is because you used an html entity.

> An HTML entity is a piece of text ("string") that begins with an ampersand (&) and ends with a semicolon (;) [Entity <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)

As a result, there is no chance for JavaScript to remedy this situation. You need to figure out a way to render the `&quot;` differently in your templating engine, ideally double-encoding the quote with `&amp;quot;` (as mentioned by [@Barmar in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393561/html-entities-converted-into-their-character-values-when-json-read-from-data-att#comment85789112_49393665)).

Comment: HTML doesn't support backslash escapes. Double-encode them: `&amp;quot;`

Comment: @Barmar - Ah, the attribute works, but the html renders incorrectly, you are right. I will edit that.